fast way of getting a subset a C# list based on a comparison
In a C# code, I need to get a subset of elements from a list of elements based on a comparison on element's attribute, i.e.
var result = from e in element_list
             where e.size < size_threshold
             select e

the elements in the element_list are already sorted based on their 'size' attribute.
this turns out to be quite slow if element_list becomes large and I do it repeatedly.
I thought about using a dictionary and get the index of size_threshold, then .GetRange() from the list, but I think dictionary doesn't maintain index order of the items it holds.

What kind of searches do you do on the list? Always the same with changing threshold values? Entirely different searches? Is element_list a List<Something>?

the size_threshold constantly changes, the element_list is not changing

Since element_list is sorted by size you can use TakeWhile operator:
var result = element_list
   .TakeWhile(e => e.size < size_threshold);

It will not enumerate whole element_list and should be faster.
